# Neural network, local minimum evasion techniques

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, neural-network

Im new in this subject and trying some different things about escaping from a local-minimum. Im using randomized learning rate and momentum but for a small percentile of trainings, it stucks and cant learn anything(sometimes stucks at beginning, sometimes middle ) even with random starting weights and biases.

I tried several different settings for teaching XOR such as:

```
 1)Faster learning but with a bigger chance of locally trapped. 
 (learns in less than 1200 iterations total)

 2)Slow learning but with evading local minimum better.
 (learns under 40k iterations total)

 3)Very steep learning with ~%50 chance of pit-fall(learns under 300 iterations total)
```

**Question:** Is throwing several students into training and selecting the best learner worthy? Or do we need to concentrate on getting %100 success rate for a single setting?

Example:

```
 3 students (XOR candidates) learning in parallel: 

 -First student is learning fast(learns first, tells others to stop to save cycles)
 -Other two are slow learners to increase success rate of training
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many possible methods of escaping local minima. Parallel learning has been investigated in the past, with different results, but it did not get to the "global usage". Some researchers simply proposed repeated training with different parameters and/or starting points, others - tried to use other training algorithms, like [simulated annealing](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-76928-6_12) reporting good results.

The most recent methods include so called [Extreme Learning Machines](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/), where neural networks are learned in the heavily regularized form with global minimum found using Moore–Penrose pseudo inverse. If you are facing a problem of local minima in your work, I would suggest giving it a try, as a very recent, powerful and achieving suprisingly good results - model.

I do not really undestand why are you referring XOR problem, AFAIK [this problem has no local minima](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12662805).

I have never heard anyone calling a machine learning model "student", this makes the question quite weird to read. Some people are using "learner" but "student"?